# 'style' undefined Uncaught Type Error for a Progress Bar Project

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar, typeerror

I'm new to Javascript and I've been through some tutorials and project to become familiar with the language. There is one Progress-Bar tutorial I found provided by "dcode" at this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxQRtwAtqKE That I've been following along with but I seem to get an error on my java script code where the instructor does not.

It seems to be in the style method of the update function in the Javascript section.
I tried rearranging the update function's location (placed it above setValue() at one point), thinking that maybe its not able to be read where it's placed. But that did not seem to work. I followed this tutorial to the letter, so I'm not really sure how I'm getting this wrong. Is there something I'm missing?

Here is the code with a few edits from me:
Javascript code:

```js
// JavaScript source code

//creating a class for the progess bar (HP bar)
class ProgressBar {
    contructor(element, initialValue = 0) { 
        this.valueElem = element.querySelector('.HP-value');
        this.fillElem = element.querySelector('.HP-bar-fill');

        this.setValue(initialValue);

        //console.log(this.valueElem);
        //console.log(this.fillElem);
    }

    setValue(newValue) {
        if (newValue < 0) {
            newValue = 0;
        }

        if (newValue > 100) {
            newValue = 100;
        }

        this.value = newValue;
        this.update();
    }

    update() {
        const percentage = this.value + '%'; // 50%

        this.fillElem.style.width = percentage;  //Error displays for me here but not the instructor.
        this.valueElem.textContent = percentage;
        
        
    }
}


const pb1 = new ProgressBar(document.querySelector('.HP'), 80); 
//calls the value from user to display the new percentage. 
//In this case it should go from 50% to 80%.
```

```css
body
{
}

.HP {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.HP-bar-fill {
    height: 100%;
    background: #36ed1a;
    transition: width 0.5s;
}

.HP-value {
    position: absolute; /*float above the nearest parent positioned element*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--Create your own progress bar in HTML, CSS, and Javascript | Web development tutorial-->
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <title>HealthBar</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Your HP</h1>
    <div class="HP">
        <div class="HP-value">50%</div>
        <div class="HP-bar-fill"></div>

    </div>


    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the error say? Try `console.log(percentage);` right before that line

Comment: The error is: script.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at ProgressBar.update (script.js:31)
    at ProgressBar.setValue (script.js:25)
    at <anonymous>:1:5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JS, you have made a typo for 'constructor'. You have called it 'contructor' because of which it never gets called and your  `this.fillElem.style.width = percentage;` throws undefined because JS has no idea where fillElem came from and that in itself is undefined. So in your JS code fix that constructor typo:

```
//creating a class for the progess bar (HP bar)
class ProgressBar {
    constructor(element, initialValue = 0) { 
      console.log('constructor called');
        this.valueElem = element.querySelector('.HP-value');
        this.fillElem = element.querySelector('.HP-bar-fill');
        
        this.setValue(initialValue);

        //console.log(this.valueElem);
       
    }

    setValue(newValue) {
        if (newValue < 0) {
            newValue = 0;
        }

        if (newValue > 100) {
            newValue = 100;
        }

        this.value = newValue;
        this.update();
    }

    update() {
        const percentage = this.value + '%'; // 50%
        this.fillElem.style.width = percentage;  //Error displays for me here but not the instructor.
        this.valueElem.textContent = percentage;
        
        
    }
}


const pb1 = new ProgressBar(document.querySelector('.HP'), 80); 
//calls the value from user to display the new percentage. 
//In this case it should go from 50% to 80%.
```

Here's the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/0b7cs35x/

Comment: Oh my goodness! That was it! Corrected that on my page and it is working now! Can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help! Often times its these little things. I would recommend adding a linter to you IDE https://eslint.org/ to guard against such errors. Also please accept my answer. thanks!